# Throw new Exception and catch that immediately to avoid code repetition. Possible?

Tags: java, exception, repeat

So, basically I have this kind of code, where repetition happens:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataFromApi.size(); i++){

        try {
            returnedPoolData = dataFromApi.get(i).get();

            if(returnedPoolData == null || returnedPoolData.getJsonString().isEmpty())
                this.processAndStoreData(returnedPoolData, i, calledApis, id, true);
            else
                this.processAndStoreData(returnedPoolData, i, calledApis, id, false);

        } catch (ExecutionException e){
            log.info("" + e);
            this.processAndStoreData(returnedPoolData, i, calledApis, id, true);
        }
    }
```

I would like to avoid repetition by throwing a `IllegalArgumentException` and catching that immediately in catch block.

So the code would look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataFromApi.size(); i++){

        try {
            returnedPoolData = dataFromApi.get(i).get();

            if(returnedPoolData == null || returnedPoolData.getJsonString().isEmpty())
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Returned data was empty.");
            else
                this.processAndStoreData(returnedPoolData, i, calledApis, id, false);

        } catch (ExecutionException e){
            log.info("" + e);
            this.processAndStoreData(returnedPoolData, i, calledApis, id, true);
        }
    }
```

Would that work? Cause as soon as I remove the `ExecutionException` the `throw new` line doesn't underline in red...

Comment: Why do you throw IllegalArgumentException, but try to catch ExecutionException? And can you be more specific about error? What causes the red underline?

Comment: The use of exceptions for control flow is an anti-pattern, with notable situation- and language-specific exceptions. Please see: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why

Comment: In your catch block, can `processAndStoreData` throw an `ExecutionException`? If that is not the case, then you can take them out of the try-catch block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IllegalArgumentException` is a runtime exception.
So the compiler doesn't constraint you to handle it.
I would add that the `ExecutionException` `catch` statement will not be helpful either to handle the `IllegalArgumentException` throwing :

```
catch (ExecutionException e){
    log.info("" + e);
    this.processAndStoreData(returnedPoolData, i, calledApis, id, true);
}
```

as `IllegalArgumentException` is not a subclass of `ExecutionException`.
To caught both exception, you could write a catch statement such as :

```
catch (ExecutionException | IllegalArgumentException e){
   ...
}
```

---

Beyond the way of catching an exception correctly, I would add that throwing an exception to catch it in the same method is not necessarily a good use of the exceptions.
An alternative way to avoid the three duplicate invocation is using a boolean such as :

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataFromApi.size(); i++) {

    boolean isErrorCase = false;

    try {
        returnedPoolData = dataFromApi.get(i).get();

        if (returnedPoolData == null || returnedPoolData.getJsonString().isEmpty()) {              
            isErrorCase = true;
        }

    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        log.info("" + e);
        isErrorCase = true;
    }

    this.processAndStoreData(returnedPoolData, i, calledApis, id, isErrorCase);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should throw when the returned data is null. But you also shouldn't catch an exception when you don't intend or cannot handle it.

So if you just intent to log the error and continue on add a `IllegalArgumentException` to your existing catch clause or add another catch clause to handle this kind of exception.

Otherwise if you can't handle it here, let it *propagate*.

Also if a `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown, `catch(ExecutionException){...}` will not catch it, since 
 `IllegalArgumentException` is not detived from  `ExecutionException`.